# Perl: How can I use an existing package as a base for a new class/object

Tags: perl, oop

I have a Perl package which wasn't written as an OOP class. Let's call it PkgA. PkgA has subroutines and variables defined.

I'd like to instantiate it twice in my main package, with each instance having its own set of values for  the package's variables.

I thought that turning PkgA into a class, and instantiating it twice by constructing 2 objects of that class would be the correct path to take.

To demonstrate my problem I created two files: PkgA.pm and Mail.pl - they appear at the bottom.

PkgA contains a mix of object variables and local variables.

object variables : `_CoreName`, `_is_uchipsim_test`, and `OOPVar`. They represent those variables I added when converting PkgA into an object.

local variable: `NonOOPVar`. It represents original PkgA variables.

The program creates two instances of PkgA under Main: main_PkgA and aux_PkgA. Then it calls process_args for main_PkgA followed by aux_PkgA.

process_args assigns values to `OOPVar` and  `NonOOPVar`.
In main_PkgA they will be {100,101} and in aux_PkgA they will be {200,201}.

Then the program calls load_mem in both instances.
This subroutine only prints OOPVar and NonOOPVar.
You can see in the output printed to the screen that:

```
main_PkgA: NonOOPVar = 200, OOPVar = 101
aux_PkgA  : NonOOPVar = 200, OOPVar = 201
```

So, the OOPVar both have the correct values but NonOOPVar of main_PkgA carries the value of aux_PkgA!

I need to find a way to make NonOOPVar be aware of the instance it belongs to.

---

### **PkgA.pm**:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

package PkgA;
require 5.000;

push(@ISA,PkgA.pm);
 
sub new {
    print ("Package PkgA::new was called \n");
    my $class = shift;
    # Receive parameters from the containing module
    my $self = {
        _CoreName         => shift,
        _is_uchipsim_test => shift,
        OOPVar            => None
    };
    printf("Class = %s, Core name = %s is_uchipsim_test = %d, OOPVar = %d\n",$class,$self->{_CoreName},$self->{_is_uchipsim_test},$self->{OOPVar});
    bless $self, $class;
    return $self;
};

sub get_core_name {
    my ($self) = shift;
    return $self->{_CoreName};
}
sub get_is_uchipsim_test {
    my ($self) = shift;
    return $self->{_is_uchipsim_test};
}

my ($NonOOPVar);
sub process_args {  
    $this = shift @_;
    my (@args) = @_;
    $NonOOPVar = @args[0];
    $this->{OOPVar} = $NonOOPVar + 1;
    printf("this = %s, args size = %d, args[0] = %s, NonOOPVar = %d, OOPVar = %d\n",$this, scalar @args, $args[0],$NonOOPVar,$this->{OOPVar});
};

sub load_mem {
    $this = shift @_;
    printf("load_mem, this = %s, NonOOPVar = %d, OOPVar = %d  \n",$this, $NonOOPVar,$this->{OOPVar});
};

1;
```

---

### Main.pl

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use PkgA;

$main_PkgA       = new PkgA("PkgA_main",1); # Arguments of new(): _CoreName, _is_uchipsim_test,
$aux_PkgA        = new PkgA("PkgA_aux" ,2);
$MainCoreName    = $main_PkgA->get_core_name();
$AuxCoreName     = $aux_PkgA->get_core_name();
printf("Main: Instantiate systest_dot11acphy for MAIN core. Printing its CoreName field: %s\n",$main_PkgA->get_core_name());
printf("Main: Instantiate systest_dot11acphy for AUX  core. Printing its CoreName field: %s\n",$aux_PkgA->get_core_name());

$main_PkgA->process_args(100);
$aux_PkgA->process_args(200);

$main_PkgA->load_mem();
$aux_PkgA->load_mem();
```

Comment: The variables (both lexical and package variables) declared in the package scope in `PkgA.pm` are related to the package. They are separate from the variables in the `$self` hash created in the `new()` sub which are local to each object. You need to move the package variables that should be local to each object into the `$self` hash.

Answer (score 1):

A few things wrong with this. Firstly, use strict and warnings will help you with nearly all of your errors.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
```

use this to create new objects. Your other way was the indirect object notation. [which is bad](http://www.modernperlbooks.com/mt/2009/08/the-problems-with-indirect-object-notation.html)

```
$aux_PkgA        = PkgA->new("PkgA_aux" ,2);
```

Use $ to get a single value and @ to get multiple values

```
sub process_args {  
my $this = shift @_;
my (@args) = @_;
$this->{NonOOPVar} = $args[0];
$this->{OOPVar} = $this->{NonOOPVar} + 1;
printf("this = %s, args size = %d, args[0] = %s, NonOOPVar = %d, OOPVar = %d\n",$this, scalar @args, $args[0],$this->{NonOOPVar},$this->{OOPVar});
};
```

you were calling a value which you didn't want to call. You initiated a variable $NonOOPVar which was not local to the object. It was shared between objects because it was in the main program scope. Use strict and warning would make it clear how this occurred and you would not be able to do this.

```
 printf("load_mem, this = %s, NonOOPVar = %d, OOPVar = %d  \n",$this, $this->{NonOOPVar},$this->{OOPVar});
```

**PkgA.pm**

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
package PkgA;
my $NonOOPVar = 200;
sub new {
    print ("Package PkgA::new was called \n");
    my $class = shift;
    # Receive parameters from the containing module
    my $self = {
        _CoreName         => shift,
        _is_uchipsim_test => shift,
        OOPVar            => undef
    };
    printf("Class = %s, Core name = %s is_uchipsim_test = %d, OOPVar = %d\n",$class,$self->{_CoreName},$self->{_is_uchipsim_test},$self->{OOPVar});
    bless $self, $class;
    return $self;
};

sub get_core_name {
    my ($self) = shift;
    return $self->{_CoreName};
}
sub get_is_uchipsim_test {
    my ($self) = shift;
    return $self->{_is_uchipsim_test};
}

sub process_args {  
    my $this = shift @_;
    my (@args) = @_;
    $this->{NonOOPVar} = $args[0];
    $this->{OOPVar} = $this->{NonOOPVar} + 1;
    printf("this = %s, args size = %d, args[0] = %s, NonOOPVar = %d, OOPVar = %d\n",$this, scalar @args, $args[0],$this->{NonOOPVar},$this->{OOPVar});
};

sub load_mem {
    my $this = shift @_;
    printf("load_mem, this = %s, NonOOPVar = %d, OOPVar = %d  \n",$this, $this->{NonOOPVar},$this->{OOPVar});
    #printf("load_mem, this = %s, NonOOPVar = %d, OOPVar = %d  \n",$this, $NonOOPVar,$this->{OOPVar});

};

1;
```

**Main.pl**

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use PkgA;

my $main_PkgA       = PkgA->new("PkgA_main",1); # Arguments of new(): _CoreName, _is_uchipsim_test,
my $aux_PkgA        = PkgA->new("PkgA_aux" ,2);
my $MainCoreName    = $main_PkgA->get_core_name();
my $AuxCoreName     = $aux_PkgA->get_core_name();
printf("Main: Instantiate systest_dot11acphy for MAIN core. Printing its CoreName field: %s\n",$main_PkgA->get_core_name());
printf("Main: Instantiate systest_dot11acphy for AUX  core. Printing its CoreName field: %s\n",$aux_PkgA->get_core_name());

$main_PkgA->process_args(100);
$aux_PkgA->process_args(200);

$main_PkgA->load_mem();
$aux_PkgA->load_mem();
```

Comment: You're right, I always thought use strict and warnings are applied to all files included libs when called. I guess i was wrong. Modified the two errors

Comment: They are lexically-scoped (like `my`)

Comment: Thank you @hoffmeister. I adopted your comments.
The motivation for my question is that my original package contains a large number of variables which I'd like to turn into object's variables. Moving all of them into the \@self hash of the object is expected to be very time consuming, so I was looking for some sophisticated way to do that. I guess I'll have to go the full way